# How to fix EF Core migration error on join table configuration

Tags: entity-framework-core

Using EF core 6.0.1, I'm following the example shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#join-entity-type-configuration) for configuring the join table for a many-to-many relationship in a migration, but I can't get past this error:

> The seed entity for entity type 'Classifier' cannot be added because
> no value was provided for the required property 'Id'.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Classifier>().HasData(
                    new Classifier
                    {
                        Id = 1,
                        Name = "Concerto",
                    }
    );

modelBuilder.Entity<Composition>()
                .HasData(
                    new Composition
                    {
                        Id = -1,
                        Name = "First Composition",
                        CreatorId = -1,
                        LastModifierId = -1,
                        CreatedDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2019"),
                        LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2019"),
                        Summary = "Lorem ipsum",
                    }
                );

modelBuilder.Entity<Classifier>()
                .HasMany(cl => cl.Compositions)
                .WithMany(cm => cm.Classifiers)
                .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("ClassifierCompositions")
            )
            .HasData(
                            new { ClassifiersId = 1, CompositionsId = -1, },
                            
            );
```

I've verified that the names used in the anonymous type used to configure the join match the autogenerated column names from EF. I suspect the error message is a poor representation of the real error, since clearly the Classifier.Id is provided. Why is this error being thrown?

Fwiw, the Composition table exists already as created by a previous migration and this migration is adding the Classifier table and join table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I suspect the error message is a poor representation of the real error, since clearly the `Classifier.Id` is provided. Why is this error being thrown?

Actually the error is correct. It's because here

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Classifier>()
                .HasMany(cl => cl.Compositions)
                .WithMany(cm => cm.Classifiers)
                .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("ClassifierCompositions")
            ) // <-- the problem
            .HasData(
                            new { ClassifiersId = 1, CompositionsId = -1, },
                            
            );
```

you are executing the `UsingEntity` call, which returns `EntityTypeBuilder<Classifier>`, so the next `HasData` call is actually defining more `Classifier` data entries via anonymous type which of course has no `Id` property, hence the error message.

The correct action of course is to define the seed data for the join entity, using its entity builder inside the `UsingEntity` call, i.e.

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Classifier>()
    .HasMany(cl => cl.Compositions)
    .WithMany(cm => cm.Classifiers)
    .UsingEntity(j => j
        .ToTable("ClassifierCompositions")
        .HasData(
            new { ClassifiersId = 1, CompositionsId = -1, },
        )                    
    );
```

Comment: LOL! Knew it would be something dumb like that. Thanks for the sensible explanation.